# Ambiguous labels for AA battery insertion

Tags: batteries

I have a consumer device that accepts two AA batteries.  The battery chamber is designed such that the batteries are inserted from open end of the chamber rather than the side (i.e. along the axis of each battery).  The '+' and '-' labels are also located on the end of the chamber next to the "holes" that accommodate each battery.  The positioning of the labels is ambiguous -- it depends on the conceptual model of what you think the labels are asking:  1) "insert the battery such that the end of the battery matching this symbol goes into the hole first", or 2) "insert the battery such that the end of the battery that is visible after insertion matches this symbol".  A little research on this revealed that one can almost always determine the correct orientation by making sure that the negative side of the battery goes against the spring contact, but I have seen some references that state that this is not universally true.  In this case, the answer is option 2.

Is there a standard for labeling such "vertical" battery containers to resolve the ambiguity?  Has anyone seen a product that accepts AA or AAA batteries that did not follow the design noted above?

[image: top view]

Comment: For AA, I've always hoped that manufacturers would use the springy end of the holder for the (-) battery terminal and the bump-end of the holder for the (+) battery terminal. ***But that's not always the case.*** Just a few days ago, in fact, I just replaced the two AA batteries in a device where it wasn't the case. So no, you can't even assume that much. Still, they will often emboss the plastic below to show an image of the battery (or the lid cover above.) But still again, even that isn't always the case. The only thing you can be sure of is that there's nothing for certain.

Comment: Would you please add an image of the case and markings?

Comment: Is there any molded feature that looks like it's intended to polarize the insertion?

Comment: I've never seen #1. Show us the marking.

Comment: Image added.  As you can see, there are no molded features that serve as forcing functions for proper battery insertion.

Comment: It's #2. Even the contacts match (spring for the negative contact, flat contact for the positive contact. Like I said earlier, I have never seen #1.

Comment: what do the lid contacts look like?

Comment: if you put a cell on right side with negative end down, then will the cell make contact with the coiled wire? ... there may be a ridge that allows only the positive end to make contact

Comment: To answer the last two questions: 1) the lid contacts look similar to the contacts at the bottom (interior), with one of them being a spring and the other a flat contact; 2) the batteries can be inserted incorrectly and there is nothing preventing them from making contact.  I think for the majority of devices, the device will simply do nothing if batteries are inserted backwards.  But for a few, it might do some damage.

But to the original question, no one so far has pointed to a standard for placement of labeling.  If it's not a written standard, perhaps it is a defacto industry standard.

Answer (score 0):

On every piece of equipment I have used, the markings mean "this end of the battery here."

That's your option 2.